# how to convert a specific date into other date format in Load Runner?

Tags: c, date, loadrunner

I want to convert a date (eg. 6/19/2017) into 20170619 this format with standard C. Any help will be useful for me.
Note: The input date is random.

Comment: This is a generic C language question, not really related to LoadRunner

Comment: Why programming skills are foundational to any performance testing tool